# UV/Texture Mapping in Python

Tags: python, 3d, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I have on quick question.  I want to know if it is possible to perform UV/Texture mapping within python.  I know I would probably need to import a module or two.  But I haven't too many examples of how to perform UV/texture mapping in python.
If it possible could someone post up an example.
Ultimately what I want to do is to import a 3D model that was created in a 3D program (say blender or 3D max) then I need to apply data to the surface of this 3D model.  The data would be in the form of a matrix or array.  I know UV/Texture mapping can help make this process easier that is why I am curious about do this.